# Is there a generic 'FuncSTA' for invoking delegates by a STA thread?

Tags: asp.net, com, components, sta

I have an `ASP.NET` application and need to use some `COM` components inside it.

I need a wrapper class over `Func` or `Action` which creates a new `STA` thread and run the delegate with that thread or something like this. Do you know such a class or library out of the box or a sample code ?

```
CodeUsingComComponent.InvokeSTA()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such method exists.
You can write one yourself:

```
public static void InvokeSTA(this ThreadStart method) {
    var thread = new Thread(method);
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}
```

If you want to invoke it synchronously, add `thread.Join()`.